# Correctly setting up SSTP on Amazon EC2 Server 2008 Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-web-services, sstp

I have successfully setup up a VPN connection to an EC2 instance of Windows Server 2008 using SSTP. But the setup seems a little hacked together and needs some tweeking. My first problem/question is that I still have to individually configure each user account for Dial-In access. I would like to keep the "Control Access through NPS Network Policy" setting but right now the only way is to set "Network Access Permission" to "Allow Access" for each user account.

Second question: [Setting up GPO to apply upon SSTP VPN login](https://serverfault.com/questions/485371/setting-up-gpo-to-apply-upon-sstp-vpn-login)

Third question:  [Setting up DNS to work over SSTP VPN Connection to Amazon EC2 instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/485382/setting-up-dns-to-work-over-sstp-vpn-connection-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Got all three issues resolved. Needed to enable RRAS and configure an NPS policy for the network.